# Web-based contact management software

Tags: open-source, web-apps, self-hosted, contact-manager

I am looking for a contact management software that needs to be open source. 
I would like it to be a web app for self hosting, so that I can install it on a web server and have access to it from anywhere

I am not looking for CRM software. This is not for marketing or for sales.

I have a number of business cards and I would like to have a piece of software that would help me manage all of the contacts that I have. It would also be nice if the software could keep track of the emails that I send out and contain a list of the incoming/outgoing emails for each specific contact.

Comment: gmail does this, but it isn't open source.

Comment: How about owncloud?

Comment: It looks like it is a sync app, I am looking for something that can organize everything based on contacts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Monica](https://www.monicahq.com) is an open source personal relationship management system. It's written in PHP and uses MySQL as the database. From https://github.com/monicahq/monica#features:

- Add and manage contacts
- Define relationships between contacts
- Reminders
- Automatic reminders for birthdays
- Stay in touch with a contact by sending reminders at a given interval
- Management of debts
- Ability to add notes to a contact
- Ability to record how you met someone
- Management of activities with a contact
- Management of tasks
- Management of gifts given and received and ideas for gifts
- Management of addresses and all the different ways to contact someone
- Management of contact field types
- Management of a contact’s pets
- Basic journal
- Ability to record how your day went
- Upload documents and photos
- Export and import of data
- Export contacts as vCards
- Ability to define custom genders
- Ability to define custom activity types
- Ability to favorite contacts
- Track conversations on social media or SMS
- Multiple users
- Tags to organize contacts
- Ability to define what section should appear on the contact sheet
- Multiple currencies
- Multiple languages
- An API that covers most of the data